# Relacionar Produtos com EANS duplicados em uma relação onde 1 produto possui n EANS. Linguagem sql

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, query

Como poderia para fazer a comparação com a EAN de outro produto, sem que eu a compare o mesmo produto... em sql?

```
CREATE TABLE `produto`(
`idproduto` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`nome` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`idproduto`)
)

CREATE TABLE `eans` (
`cod_produto` INT NOT NULL,
`ean` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (`cod_produto`)
REFERENCES `produto` (`idproduto`)  
);
```

Comment: coloque na pergunta o modelo de dados, estrutura das tabelas, porque assim fica difícil ajudar

Comment: A princípio você poderia identificar os EANS duplicados utilizando a cláusula `HAVING COUN(*) > 1` juntamente com um `GROUP BY EANS`.

Answer (score 0):

Caso você queira identificar os produtos que, apesar de terem códigos diferentes, possuam o mesmo EAN tente:

```
SELECT ean, GROUP_CONCAT(cod_produto) 
FROM eans
GROUP BY ean
HAVING COUNT(cod_produto) > 1
```

Se não for isso explique melhor o que deseja, se possível com algum exemplo.

Comment: exatamente éssa a quetão, vou tentar aqui obrigado